# Replacing values in a matrix for a selected number of columns

Tags: r, matrix, replace

In a given matrix `a`, with integers and some `NA` :
If I want to replace all `NA` with 99, I do :

```
a[is.na(a)]<-99
```

Should I want to do the same for column 2 only, the following works well :

```
a[is.na(a[,2]),2]<-99
```

But if I want to do this for, say, col 1 and 2, this does not work :

```
a[is.na(a[,1:2]),1:2]<-99
```

neither

```
a[is.na(a[,c(1:2)]),c(1:2)]<-99
```

It says (sorry, in French) :

> Error in `[<-`(`*tmp*`, is.na(a[, c(1:2)]), c(1:2), value = 99) :
>   (subscript) indice logique trop long

Does anyone have an idea why?

Comment: If the question is *why* rather *how*, then the answer is because `is.na(a[,c(1:2)])` already returns a two dimensional logical *matrix*, and together with `c(1:2)` you have too many dimension that a `matrix` can handle. When debugging in R, you should work from inside out and check what the inner function do first, before checking the final operation.

Answer (score 1):

First subset the matrix and then find NAs.

```
set.seed(123)
xy <- matrix(NA, ncol = 3, nrow = 3)
xy[sample(1:9, 4)] <- runif(4)
xy

          [,1]      [,2]      [,3]
[1,] 0.7883051 0.4089769        NA
[2,]        NA        NA        NA
[3,]        NA 0.8830174 0.2875775

xy[, 1:2][is.na(xy)[, 1:2]] <- 99
xy

           [,1]       [,2]      [,3]
[1,]  0.7883051  0.4089769        NA
[2,] 99.0000000 99.0000000        NA
[3,] 99.0000000  0.8830174 0.2875775
```